# Date MS access vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to update an item's expiration date in MS access but It throws a data type mismatch

This is the code I used to update the item please check this Thanks I tried doing addwithvalue and add("expD",oledbtype.Date) Non works

```
Query
query = "Update Medicines set BarcodeID = @BarcodeID, Drugs =@DrugName, Dosage = @Dosage, Quantity= @Quantity, Station =@Station, ExpD =@ExpDate,  Price=@Price, stckid=@stckid, IsActive='" & ComboBox1.Text & "' where BarcodeID=@BarcodeID"
```

My parameters

```
 cmd.CommandText = query
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarcodeID", txtbarcode.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrugName", txtdrugs.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dosage", txtdosage.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtquantity.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", txtstation.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtprice.Text)
                        'cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpD", OleDbType.Date)
                        'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpDate", dtExpD.Value.Date)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtExpD.Value.Date
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stckid", txtstockid.Text)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsActive", OleDbType.LongVarChar)
                        cmd.Parameters("@IsActive").Value = combocontainer
```

Thanks

Comment: You should ALWAYS strive to be consistent in writing your code. Doing the same thing multiple different ways is never a good thing because anyone reading your code might wonder what the reason is when there's no reason at all. NEVER use `AddWithValue`. ALWAYS use `Add` and ALWAYS set the `Value` on the same line. The way you're doing it for `"@ExpDate"` is the way you should be doing it for ALL parameters. For the text columns, you need to specify the size as well as the data type.

Comment: Every time you name something - variable, property, method, event, type, etc. - the name should be descriptive of what the thing does. How can you be setting a parameter named `"@IsActive"` with a variable named `combocontainer`? That appears to be an absolutely terrible variable name.

Comment: It is assumed that there is proper validation of user input, and it seems that you are using a datetimepicker control for the date. For the price (and also the quantity, possibly more), if you are using a regular textbox, I would instead suggest that you use a [numericupdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netframework-4.8) control, so as to disallow invalid input characters. It is also possible to use decimals and constrain the price within a predetermined range. This would be a small improvement to your UI and require less validation.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using parameter names in your SQL code, the Jet and ACE OLE DB providers ignore those names and substitute values from parameters into the SQL code based on position. That means that you MUST add the parameters to the command in the same order as they appear in the SQL code. You ought to do that regardless but it is essential for Access databases. Your SQL code contains `"ExpD =@ExpDate,  Price=@Price"` but you add parameters like this:

```vb
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtprice.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = Me.dtExpD.Value.Date
```

The order is reversed so those values are actually getting used the wrong way around. At least you were alerted by the data type mismatch. If they had been the same type then it would have worked but saved the wrong data to the wrong columns.